# binomial distribution/ poisson distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I was wondering if anyone can please check this problem and let me know if I did this correct? Below is what i did to work out the problem. Thanks

Problem: The number of cars that arrive at a car wash follows Poisson distribution with the rate of 10.5 cars per hour. Assume that the number of cars that arrive during each hour are independent. (define a random variable for each part/problem)

d) Find the probability that there is at least one hour in a four hour period where only 5 cars arrive?

I believe this problem is both binomial and poisson distribution.

n= 4   , lambda= 10.5 , p=?
Let Y represent the # of hours within a four hour period where only 5 cars arrive.

poisson distribution
p= P(y=5)=poissonpdf(10.5,5)≈ 0.0293 therefore p=0.0293

binomial distribution
P(x≥1) = 1 - P(x≤0)= 1- binomcdf(4,.0293,0)≈ 0.1121

Please let me know if I did any of these steps wrong! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Yes.   You are using that $(Y_k)\overset{iid}\sim\mathcal {Pois}(10.5)$ and $X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(4,\mathsf P(Y_1=5))$ to find $\mathsf P(X\geq 1)$.

Justification: $X$ is the count of successes in 4 *independent* trials, each with an **identical** *success rate*, where a trial's success is defined as obtaining exactly 5 arrivals from its Poisson process with *arrival rate* $10.5$ per the trial interval (one hour).

So as $\mathsf P(Y_1=5)=\dfrac{(10.5)^5 \mathsf e^{-10.5}}{5!}$, then $\mathsf P(X\geq 1)=1-\left(1-\dfrac{(10.5)^5\mathsf e^{-10.5}}{5!}\right)^4$.

That is indeed approximately $0.112101...$